# Ruby: install a yanked gem (e.g. wkpdf on OS X 10.9)

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-mavericks

I'd like to install wkpdf as per https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122176/convert-html-to-pdf-with-page-margins-and-hyperlinks, but, as per http://plessl.github.io/wkpdf/ and https://rubygems.org/gems/wkpdf, the gem "wkpdf" is "yanked", even though it should most likely still be in the working order.

```
% sudo gem install wkpdf
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'wkpdf' (>= 0) in any repository
11.556u 0.437s 0:29.63 40.4%    0+0k 57+1io 363pf+0w
```

Is there a way to install it nonetheless?  I'm running OS X 10.9, `gem -v` returns `2.0`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project is still online here:

https://github.com/plessl/wkpdf

You can do the following:

```
$ wget https://github.com/plessl/wkpdf/archive/v0.6.11.tar.gz
$ tar -xf v0.6.11.tar.gz
$ cd wkpdf-0.6.11
$ gem build wkpdf.gemspec
$ sudo gem install wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin.gem
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the webpage provides the reference to the gem file in question:

```
% curl https://rubygems.org/gems/wkpdf |& fgrep Download
        <a id="download" class="gem__link t-list__item" href="/downloads/wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin.gem">Download</a>
```

So, just doing `wget` on it, and it'll be locally available for the installation:

```
% wget https://rubygems.org/downloads/wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin.gem
```

```
% sudo gem install wkpdf
Fetching: trollop-2.1.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed trollop-2.1.2
Successfully installed wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin
Parsing documentation for trollop-2.1.2
Installing ri documentation for trollop-2.1.2
Parsing documentation for wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin
Installing ri documentation for wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin
2 gems installed
2.603u 0.478s 0:15.32 20.0% 0+0k 186+56io 403pf+0w
% wkpdf
Cannot load RubyCocoa library
wkpdf requires that RubyCocoa is installed, which is shipped by default since
Mac OS X 10.5. If you use Mac OS X 10.4, you have to install RubyCocoa
yourself from http://rubycocoa.sourceforge.net/HomePage
```

However, in the specific case of `wkpdf`, it also appears to require RubyCocoa (as per https://github.com/plessl/wkpdf/issues/45, first hit from http://www.google.ru/search?q=rubycocoa+10.9), which only works with Ruby 1.8, and not with the 2.0 (which has been made the default on OS X 10.9, even though Ruby 1.8 is also installed).

As such, wkpdf has to be uninstalled from 2.0, and installed into 1.8:

```
% sudo gem uninstall wkpdf
```

```
% sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem install wkpdf
Successfully installed trollop-2.1.2
Successfully installed wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for trollop-2.1.2...
Installing ri documentation for wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin...
Installing RDoc documentation for trollop-2.1.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin...
4.275u 0.252s 0:11.27 40.1% 0+0k 26+26io 3pf+0w
% wkpdf
Error: option --output must be specified.
Try --help for help.
```

---

In summary, on OS X 10.9:

```
wget https://rubygems.org/downloads/wkpdf-0.6.11-universal-darwin.gem
```

```
sudo /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/gem install wkpdf
```

```
wkpdf --source http://www.apple.com --output apple.wkpdf.pdf; open apple.wkpdf.pdf`
```